# Ways to say "lose money in investment"

Tags: word-choice

What are some ways to say *lose money in investment*?

In particular, is the usage of *swallow* in the following example alright?

> My money has been **swallowed** by the financial market.

Comment: More common ways of saying what I think you mean there are *"I lost my shirt in the market [crash]"*, and *"The market crash cleaned me out"*. It's just a personal opinion, but I'd rather either start with "I" as the subject (most important, since **I** am the one seriously affected), or put **"the market [crash]"** first because that was what actually *caused* the devastating loss. The money itself wasn't really an active player, so I wouldn't put it in control of the main verb.

Comment: The real question these days is are there any ways to say I made money on my investment. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

*[Swallow](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/swallow_2)* is correctly used in your example. It means taking away a large part of something valuable.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "correct". I think we can take it for granted OP means *"the market crash"*, but even recasting it thus... *My savings were swallowed by the market crash* sounds a bit "quirky" to me. Anyway, *swallow* doesn't mean *take away a large part of* - more like *consumed, rapidly, greedily, and completely*.

Comment: Jasper: Thanks! @FumbleFingers: Thanks! There is no specific reason, whether it is market crash or my investment strategy.

Answer (score 1):

You could as well use: 'The financial market has gotten my money depleted' or 'The financial market has exhausted all my money'.

Comment: I disagree with 'The financial market has gotten my money depleted'. That doesn't sound like proper English to me. Certainly very awkward.